# device:GPU not found and XLA_GPU doesn't process on TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, conda

I just changed my OS to Ubuntu and I'm not managing to use TF on my GPU. It worked just fine on windows.
I have a Nvida MX150, running on python 3.6.8 and tensorflow-gpu 1.12, from conda installation.
When I try to use `device=GPU:0` I get the message:

```
Cannot assign a device for operation Shape: Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 ].
```

But if I try XLA_GPU the jupyter cell never finishes running. XLA_CPU works just fine. Somebody  has come through a similar problem?

Comment: I have the same environment, same versions. How did you solve this?